# Is the "phrase-request" tag enough for questions about expressions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-request

For questions about expressions that are equivalent to ones used in a different language, is [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) enough, or should a different tag be used?

In other words, is there the need to distinguish between idiomatic phrases, and other phrases?

There is [expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions), but from its tag wiki, I get it should be used only for questions about the meaning of an expression. Is its tag wiki too restrictive?